# How to store the values of multiple children and execute a function in the parent component in Vue

Tags: forms, vue.js, modal-dialog, components

I have a component called Messaging Tool
[image]

Those are all the children components inside the messaging tool.

This is what it looks like visually:
[image]

Those 3 channels open forms of their own that will be used to send messages via appropriate channel.
They are those:

[image]

Once the 'Save text'  checkbox is clicked I need to export the fields in CSV.
Once this send message is clicked a confirmation modal will appear.

I have to save all those fields properties and on the parent component execute either a CSV save or send message to the API.

My question is how do I do that? How do I save children components values?
Obviously I can save the tickboxes values because they are in the main parent component, however, how do I save all those properties in a children components when a tickbox or a button in the parent button is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue 2, you can add `v-model` to all your `<child>`. That way, you can in the parent have a variable for each of your children that the children can use to sync their state to the parent:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Note that Vue 2 only supports `v-model` for a single value. If a child needs to sync multiple values to the parent, you can instead use the `.sync` modifier:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier

If you use Vue 3, you can use multiple `v-model`:

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#v-model-arguments

Comment: Thank you very much Peppe. You have saved me a lot of times and nerves.